# Composing descriptors in python

Tags: python, python-descriptors

### Background

In python, a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) is an object that defines any of `__get__`, `__set__` or `__delete__`, and sometimes also `__set_name__`. The most common use of descriptors in python is probably `property(getter, setter, deleter, description)`. The property descriptor calls the given getter, setter, and deleter when the respective descriptor methods are called.

It's interesting to note that functions are also descriptors: they define `__get__` which when called, returns a bound method.

Descriptors are used to modify what happens when an objects properties are accessed. Examples are restricting access, logging object access, or even dynamic lookup from a database.

### Problem

My question is: how do I design descriptors that are composable?

#### For example:

Say I have a `Restricted` descriptor (that only allows setting and getting when a condition of some sort is met), and a `AccessLog` descriptor (that logs every time the property is "set" or "get"). Can I design those so that I can compose their functionality when using them?

Say my example usage looks like this:

```py
class ExampleClient:
  # use them combined, preferably In any order 
  # (and there could be a special way to combine them, 
  # although functional composition makes the most sense)
  foo: Restricted(AccessLog())
  bar: AccessLog(Restricted())
  # and also use them separately
  qux: Restricted()
  quo: AccessLog()
```

I'm looking for a way to make this into a re-usable pattern, so I can make any descriptor composable. Any advice on how to do this in a pythonic manner? I'm going to experiment with a few ideas myself, and see what works, but I was wondering if this has been tried already, and if there is sort of a "best practice" or common method for this sort of thing...

Answer (score 1):

You can probably make that work. The tricky part might be figuring out what the default behavior should be for your descriptors if they don't have a "child" descriptor to delegate to. Maybe you want to default to behaving like a normal instance variable?

```
class DelegateDescriptor:
    def __init__(self, child=None):
        self.child = child
        self.name = None

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name
        if self.child is not None:
            try:
                self.child.__set_name__(owner, name)
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        if self.child is not None:
            return self.child.__get__(instance, owner)
        try:
            return instance.__dict__[self.name]   # default behavior, lookup the value
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if self.child is not None:
            self.child.__set__(instance, value)
        else:
            instance.__dict__[self.name] = value  # default behavior, store the value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        if self.child is not None:
            self.child.__delete__(instance)
        else:
            try:
                del instance.__dict__[self.name]  # default behavior, remove value
            except KeyError:
                raise AttributeError
```

Now, this descriptor doesn't actually *do* anything other than store a value or delegate to another descriptor. Your actual `Restricted` and `AccessLog` descriptors might be able to use this as a base class however, and add their own logic on top. The error checking is also very basic, you will probably want to do a better job raising the right kinds of exceptions with appropriate error messages in every use case before using this in production.